# Flutter. Navigator.pushedNamed with argument

Tags: flutter, dart

I am navigating to another widget like this, with an argument of a custom object:

```
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mortgage_screen', arguments: {'mortgageModel': mortgageModel});
```

Now, according to the flutter docs, I can get the argument in the build method of the new widget, like this:

```
final MortgageModel args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

However, I am getting this error message:

A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MortgageModel'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'MortgageModel'.

Thanks

Comment: Your arguments object is a dictionary and you're trying to assign it to your model. It should be ```ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments['mortgageModel'];```

Comment: @danypata. Then I get The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

Answer (score 1):

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mortgage_screen', arguments: {'mortgageModel': mortgageModel});
```

Should be:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/mortgage_screen', arguments: mortgageModel),
```

Your code above is passing a `Map<String,MortgageModel>` type object, not a `MortgageModel` type object.

And I'm guessing this was a typo: `!` (excalamation point) in your args assignment statement? I can't think of a reason why it would be there.

```
ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PassArgsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => PageOne(),
        PageTwo.routeName: (context) => PageTwo()
      },
    );
  }
}

class MortgageModel {
  int yearsLeft = 30;
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MortgageModel mortgageModel = MortgageModel();
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Go 2 /w Args'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, PageTwo.routeName, arguments: mortgageModel),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/pageTwo';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MortgageModel mortgageModel = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Pass Args P.2'),),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Mortgage years remaining: ${mortgageModel.yearsLeft}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried exactly this. But I get two errors. Without the ! that I use, I get this error: An expression whose value can be 'null' must be null-checked before it can be dereferenced.  Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before dereferencing it. Open documentation

Comment: When I put !, I still get this error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MortgageModel'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'MortgageModel'.

Comment: @RJB Oh, you're running on beta or master Flutter channel and have null-safety on.  You might want to study up on the requirements for null-safety or change your flutter channel to stable.

Comment: This means, with null safety on I cannot pass the argument in?

Comment: This means you get to learn about null-safety in Dart https://dart.dev/null-safety :)

Answer (score 0):

It is a type cast problem, and it seems that this problem only appear in dev or master channel. So i try to use **as** to fix it, and it works.

In your code, you can fix it by this:

```
final MortgageModel args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as MortgageModel ;
```

You can learn more about **as** here:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#type-test-operators

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.